# Openmp usage in C++ object constructors

Tags: c++, openmp

Can I use openmp in C++ objects' constructors?

What will be done, when there will be a *global* static object with such constructor?

Comment: Post some code that illustrates what you are (incoherently) asking about.

Comment: Yes, constructors run code just like everything else.

Comment: just to clarify, do you mean local or global static?  they have different initialization order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes.  imagine this to be the same as calling OpenMP function from constructor.

A second point, I do not know, it may depend on implementation.  I am fairly certain the pthreads implementation should be okay for global static objects.  http://www.terboven.com/download/poster_A0_portrait_neu_formatiert.pdf

Static initialization maybe somewhat difficult to get right, http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.12.
keep in mind that static object are initialized before main.

Comment: When will openmp start threads? At the main() start or before it?

Comment: @osgx should be whenever parallel region is encountered.
Exact thread implementation is implementation dependent (maybe reusable/ single threads)

Comment: Checked with intel open mp - it does support such constructors